# TeamCity restore TFS NuGet feed 401 unauthorized

Tags: tfs, nuget, teamcity, restore, http-status-code-401

TeamCity Professional 2019.1.2 (build 66342)

NuGet.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="TFS" value="https://tfs.mydomain.com/nuget/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have a `.NET CLI (dotnet)` `restore` build step including `Build Feature` `NuGet feed credentials`

The corresponding command works fine when run from local shell :

```
>  "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore MySolution.sln
> --packages \\packages --source https://tfs.mydomain.com/nuget/nuget --runtime win-x64 --configfile NuGet.config
```

But TeamCity job run on agent fails with `401 unauthorized` :

```
[15:30:52][restore] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.101\NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'Dapper' from remote source 'https://tfs.mydomain.com/nuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='Dapper'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.


[15:30:52][restore] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.101\NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

I assume shell dotnet restore uses my Windows login creds - exactly what's specified in my Build Feature NuGet feed credentials

Note that I can successfully use same creds in VisualStudio to Manage NuGet Packages ( restore packages on build ).

Comment: Could you open the feed url `https://tfs.mydomain.com/nuget/nuget` in the browser directly on the teamcity server? As I know, the feed on TFS server should be end with `.json` or the only alternative character you provide? And what is your nuget.exe version?

Comment: Yes on the machine where is installed TeamCity Server and Build Agent I can open feed `https://tfs.mydomain.com/nuget/nuget` in Internet Explorer ( but not Firefox ). IE seems to have cached my credentials - when I first tried this I might have been prompted to enter username/password but I don't remember for sure. Note that the TFS credentials are different from my domain login credentials to the TC server.

 I'm on NuGet.exe v4.7.0.5148

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the key of the source (TFS) and not the url itself.
Like this;

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore MySolution.sln --packages \\packages --source tfs --runtime win-x64 --configfile NuGet.config
```

If that doesn't work, try to add your user credentials [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-sources)

```
nuget sources add -name foo.bar -source C:\NuGet\local -username foo -password bar -StorePasswordInClearText -configfile %AppData%\NuGet\my.config
```

Comment: What do you mean by the key of the source ?  What special meaning does `tfs` have ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but `tfs` is interpreted as the name of a sub-folder off the current directory.